# Altering css for one specific page for mobile device in Wordpress

Tags: css

In wordpress, I added some HTML within an accordion element to add an image to the right of the text. On desktop, it looks fine. However, on mobile, about half the image appears chopped off, it would not automatically put the image below the text.

I know how to specify changes to a particular page `.page-id-24005` etc. and I know how to make changes to a mobile version `@media only screen and (max-width:480px) { /*code*/ }`.

But, what I'm struggling with is to combine the two. How do I make changes on one particular mobile page (in my case, move the image below the text)? I don't want this to affect any other pages.

I've tried this:
`@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ .responsive .page-id-24005  .image-overlay-inside {  position: relative; } }`

But it didn't really do much. Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested `position: relative;` in the inspector to confirm the style is effective? The CSS structure looks ok, is your selector correct (in sequence as well as specificity)?

Comment: Can you provide a page example ?

Comment: @Pof it's this page (http://questromworld.bu.edu/grad/car_path_test/)

Comment: @Frish Not sure what you mean by "Inspector"? I was trying to follow the examples from samples I found online but my isn't similar enough so I can't be certain if my sequence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well as you can see on the print screen of my browser inspector.

If you want to debug your code, you need to know how to use inspector in browsers. If you are using chrome, I'd recommend to read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You were right that the code is correct, I was just missing one string within the page code itself ```flex-wrap: wrap ```.  When I added that to the one ```<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;"> ```, it then worked as intended.